# to execute a request in MongoDB and Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm starting to develop requests on MongoDB in Java and I have a problem with one request. Please look at this code:

```
public void testConnexionEtComparaison {
 try {

  mongoDb = new MongoClient("10.1.0.73", 27017);
  DB db = (DB) mongoDb.getDatabase("brennus");
  collection = db.getCollection("brennus"); 
    DBObject request=new DBObject(
           find({"revue" : "TDL","num-cmde":419457,"formule" : "TEST LECTURE MENSUEL","produit" : 
               "TEST LECTURE MENSUEL","caformule" : 88.0,"ttc-net" : 88.0,"vdate-debut" : "01/01/2004","vdate-ech" : 
                   "01/01/2015","Nb-servis":12,"fidelite":12,"stat":null,"num-ctr":160080}));`

  DBCursor listOfElement = collection.find();
   while(listOfElement.hasNext()){
   DBObject element = listOfElement.next();
   System.out.println(element.toString());  
  }

 } catch (UnknownHostException unknownHost) {
  System.out.println("Connexion impossible : "
    + unknownHost.getMessage());
 } finally {
  //Déconnexion si nécessaire
  if (mongoDb != null) {
   mongoDb.close();
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is with "DBObject request". Can you give me your advice?

I have o problem in this line:

```
DBObject requete=new DBObject(
    find({"revue" : "TDL","num-cmde":419457,"formule" : "TEST LECTURE MENSUEL","produit" : 
        "TEST LECTURE MENSUEL","caformule" : 88.0,"ttc-net" : 88.0,"vdate-debut" : "01/01/2004","vdate-ech" : 
            "01/01/2015","Nb-servis":12,"fidelite":12,"stat":null,"num-ctr":160080}));`
```

Comment: Please edit your question to also tell us what, _exactly_ "the problem" is; if you get an exception, include it with a stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.I can't execute the class because Eclipse informes me that the type of the request is not correct , I edited my question.thanks in Advance

Comment: You are calling a `find` method with a string that looks like a document and passing its value to a `DBObject`.  That looks plain wrong - what does the `find` method return?  If it returns a cursor then iterate the cursor.  If it returns a `DBObject` then theres no need to pass it to the constructor of one.